# Add if statement to _underscore template

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a template that that I'm trying to not show divs if the variables been passed in are empty. the if statement around the caption div is giving me errors. Not sure how elese to do this.

```
<div class='caption'>
    <%if(name.length >1 )%><p><span>Name</span><span class='rating'><%= name %></span></p>
    <p><span>time</span><span class='time'><%= duration %> min</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try if (typeof name !== "undefined" && name !== null)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should probably be using `<%- name %>` instead of `<%= name %>`.  This is equivalent to `<%= _.escape(name) %>` and reduces your XSS risk.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth seeing what your template compiles to, but really, it is creating a function with some javascript.  Inside your `<% %>` is real javascript.  Because of this, you need to start and end the block.  Notice that I use a starting block `{` in the `if` statement and then later use the ERB-style tag to close the block

```
<div class='caption'>

<% if(name.length >1 ) { %>
  <p><span>Name</span><span class='rating'><%= name %></span></p>
<% } %>

  <p><span>time</span><span class='time'><%= duration %> min</span></p>

</div>
```

That should do er for ya!

(Note that I couldnt' tell for sure where you wanted the end of your "then" block to be, so I just guessed... move it to where you want the conditional to end)